# Receiving JSON from a website in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So I have this website that has JSON object and trying to have it as an object.

As most people do once it comes to javascript problem, I took a look into jQuery and found out about awesome function called .getJSON().  (Example is below, and one can replace file name with URL)

```
$.getJSON('ajax/test.json', function(data) {
  var items = [];

  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
  });

  $('<ul/>', {
    'class': 'my-new-list',
    html: items.join('')
  }).appendTo('body');
});
```

Which is not that hard to figure out...  But problem is, below statement.

> - Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject
>     to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve
>     data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.

Considering my page and the source page is not from same source, above method is not a possible option for me.

Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you control the source of the data?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Comment: While I do agree that above thread can possible solve my issue, my question is broader.  My question isn't limited to overcoming same-origin policy, but getting and interpreting JSON object from different URL.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/):

> If the URL includes the string "callback=?" (or similar, as defined by
>   the server-side API), the request is treated as JSONP instead.

So you need to change your url slightly to read like `http://path/to/resource?callback=?`

This only works if the resource supports JSONP, which means the server will wrap the data in a function call corresponding to your callback parameter, which jQuery will then reference in a `script` tag. If you can't use JSONP, your only option is some sort of server-side proxy.

Comment: Only if the server can send a proper `JSONP` response.